# php / merge 2 .csv files in to one

Tags: php, csv

I have 2 csv files which i need to merge.

file1.csv:

```
col1,col2,col3,col4
val1,val2,val3,val4
```

file2.csv:

```
col2,col4,col5
val22,val42,val5
```

**I need to merge this two files and create third file with this this content:**

```
col1,col2,col3,col4,col5
val1,val2,val3,val4,val5
val1,val22,val3,val42,val5
```

here is my try but result is wrong:

```
$csv1 = file('file1.csv', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
$csv2 = file('file2.csv', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
$lines = max(count($csv1), count($csv2));
$finalcsv = array();
for($i=0; $i<$lines; $i++) {
  if(isset($csv1[$i])) $finalcsv[] = $csv1[$i];
  if(isset($csv2[$i])) $finalcsv[] = $csv2[$i];
}

file_put_contents('file3.csv', implode(PHP_EOL, $finalcsv));
```

here is result of code **but its not what i need**:

```
col1,col2,col3,col4
col2,col4,col5
val1,val2,val3,val4
val22,val42,val5
```

Comment: Can you show the result it produces pls?

Answer (score 0):

Get the csv header columns and use them as index for the values:

```
$csv1Headers = explode(',', $csv1[0]);
$csv2Headers = explode(',', $csv2[0]);
$mergedHeaders = array_unique(array_merge($csv1Headers, $csv2Headers));

$lines = max(count($csv1), count($csv2));
$finalcsv = array(implode(',', $mergedHeaders));
for ($i = 1; $i < $lines; $i++) {
    if (isset($csv1[$i])) {
        // combine arrays, use an array of nulls to maintain order.
        $finalcsv[] = implode(',', array_merge(
                array_combine($mergedHeaders, array_fill(0, count($mergedHeaders), null)),
                array_combine($csv2Headers, explode(',', $csv2[$i])),
                array_combine($csv1Headers, explode(',', $csv1[$i]))
            )
        );
    }
    if (isset($csv2[$i])) {
        $finalcsv[] = implode(',', array_merge(
                array_combine($mergedHeaders, array_fill(0, count($mergedHeaders), null)),
                array_combine($csv1Headers, explode(',', $csv1[$i])),
                array_combine($csv2Headers, explode(',', $csv2[$i]))
            )
        );
    }
}
```